# How to extract text from smartart with proper text indentation?

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

I have to convert smart-art to textual view same as "convert To Text" ribbon's work highlight in below 1st image. Till now i am able to extract text from smart-art and write it to a shape. but i found below issues.

1. unable to make indentation of texts
2. After deleting the smart-art shape it add a blank shape to the slide.

   below is the code what I have

   ```
   private void ChangeSmartartToText(ref PresentationEXT textDeck, string deckType)
   {
       PPT.Slide slide = textDeck.destinationPresentation.Slides[textDeck.currentSlideNumber+1];
       PPT.Shape tempSmartShape = null;

       foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape in slide.Shapes)
       {
           if (shape.HasSmartArt == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
           {
               tempSmartShape = shape;
               break;
           }
       }
       PPT.Shape newTextShape = null;
       if (tempSmartShape != null)
       {
           var smartartTop = tempSmartShape.Top;
           var smartartLeft = tempSmartShape.Left;
           var smartartHeight = tempSmartShape.Height;
           var smartartWidth = tempSmartShape.Width;

           newTextShape = slide.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, smartartLeft, smartartTop, smartartWidth, smartartHeight);

           var val1 = tempSmartShape.SmartArt;
           string name = val1.Layout.Name;
           string category = val1.Layout.Category;
           StringBuilder smartartText = new StringBuilder();
           foreach (SmartArtNode node in val1.AllNodes)
           {
               smartartText.AppendLine(node.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text);
           }
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange objText;
           objText = newTextShape.TextFrame.TextRange;
           newTextShape.TextFrame.Orientation = MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal;
           objText.Text = smartartText.ToString();

           tempSmartShape.Delete();
           tempSmartShape = null;
       }
   }
   ```

   from the above code I got the out put(shown in the 2nd image) and also show what i need.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: In this case, the smartart shape is inside a content placeholder rather than being directly on the slide. When you delete the content from a content placeholder, it reverts to being an empty placeholder; you'll want to delete it too.  You can check for these by testing the shape's type; if it's a placeholder, test the placeholder type. If it's a content placeholder you can look at the contained type.

Comment: Hi @SteveRindsberg thanks for idea. It looks nice. but there may be a problem, slide may contain another place holder and it is difficult to identify have you any demo code for this. I also tried but unable to find a way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of VBA you can start with. After each If/Then that includes one of the application defined constants (msoThis or ppThat) I've added a comment with the actual value of the constant (Longs in VBAspeak, probably Integers in .Net)

```
Sub Thing()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            If oSh.Type = msoSmartArt Then ' 24
                MsgBox "SMARTART!"
            End If
            If oSh.Type = msoPlaceholder Then ' 14
                If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderObject Then ' 7
                    If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.ContainedType = msoSmartArt Then
                        MsgBox "SMARTART!"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi steve your script is for identifying whether the shape contain smartart or not. how to delete the placeholder In my code I simply take the smartart to a variable and at the end I just delete the shape. from where I can delete the placeHolder?

Comment: If you delete the shape (oSh.Delete) in the code example, it deletes the SmartArt and the original placeholder, but PPT adds a new placeholder (with a different name).  If you know there'll only be one such placeholder on a slide, you can use a variant of the same code to locate the ppPlaceholderObject type and delete the shape.  Or add the names of all the shapes on the slide to an array first, delete the SmartArt, then delete any new shapes that aren't included in the array: that'd be the new placeholder shape that PPT added. Or possibly oSl.Shapes(oSl.Shapes.Count).Delete  (delete top shp)

Comment: yes nice Idea and working perfectly. Can you change your answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi Steve I put the same question @ Microsoft portal I got answer of 1st question but i have a small issue with that I cannot apply IndentLevel more then 5 from code where as i can add IndentLevel up to 9 from powerpoint Editor. have you any idea on that?
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89187ba0-a417-49d8-85b1-406c52bf0046/how-to-add-multiple-bullet-to-a-shape-in-power-point?forum=officegeneral

Answer (score 0):

Here's another VBA snippet that demonstrates how to set indent levels via the object model; it works from 1 to 9 (but in older versions of PPT, only 5 levels are supported).

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim x As Long
Dim lIndent As Long

Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

With oSh.TextFrame2.TextRange
    For x = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
        .Paragraphs(x).ParagraphFormat.IndentLevel = x
    Next
End With
```